# How to make a package upgradeable again after manually installing a specific version?

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, apt, downgrade

My aim was to switch from a testing to a stable repository. To do that I removed the testing repo, added the stable repo and then installed a specific version from the stable repository. Unfortunately I am now not able to upgrade to a newer version in the stable repository with `apt upgrade`. I am told the package already has the most current version, which is not true. So any advice how I can enable upgrades again without having to purge the package altogether?

Comment: What package? Did you perform an `apt update` first to retrieve the latest list from the repos? Please update your question with this info.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. I had wrong version numbers in mind and thought the system would not upgrade to a newer version (that did not exist in reality). So everything worked as expected.